# Regenerate indexes after changing length of VARCHAR field

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-indexes

I have an `InnoDB` table in my MySQL database. In it, I have a field (not a primary key) that is `VARCHAR(20)`. And it is indexed.

But recently, I had to increase the size to `75`. That is, `VARCHAR(75)`

So, do I have to do anything to re-index this field? Or does the indexes gets updated automatically or won't be affected?

At the moment, this table contains only around 2000 rows.

Also, what if it was the PRIMARY KEY field which I want to increase the size ? That is, suppose my primary key is `VARCHAR` and wish to increase the field length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing size of varchar does not affect indicex. You can continue using without re-creating your indices.

Comment: Thank you. So, I have to bother only if the length is decreased or the datatype is changed? In such cases, I have to use the `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename` for this?

Comment: if you decrease column size you may need to be carefull since it may end up with data loss. and yes you may need to optimize your table or recreate your indices. You need to check whether your index is fragmented or not. check this : https://serverfault.com/a/265885/458296

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost never necessary for an InnoDB table.  Furthermore, for a "tiny" 2000-row table, defrag, poor stats, etc, are not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 2):

The indexes are updated when you change column definitions.

`ANALYZE TABLE mytable;` is always a good idea after making major changes to a table; it updates index statistics so the query planner can do the best possible job.

Major changes include many inserts, deletes, or updates to indexed columns, as well as ALTERing the table.